# SvelteKit and keycloak-js, code_to_token_error and invalid_client_credentials error

Tags: keycloak, sveltekit, keycloak-services

I'm using [keycloak-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-js) to secure my sveltekit UI app.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
    import type { KeycloakInitOptions }  from "keycloak-js";
    onMount(  () => {
        let instance = {
            url: "http://localhost:8080",
            realm: "my-realm",
            clientId: "my-client"
        };
        let keycloak = new Keycloak(instance);
        let initOptions: KeycloakInitOptions = { onLoad: "login-required" 
        };
        keycloak.init(initOptions).then(function (authenticated) {
                console.info("authorized);
            }).catch(function () {
                alert("unauthorized");
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

I'm receiving this error on my keycloak deployed in docker.

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-69) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=..., clientId=my-client, userId=null, ipAddress=..., error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=authorization_code
```

Retrieving the token from postman works though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your error message:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-69) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=..., clientId=my-client, userId=null, ipAddress=..., error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=authorization_code
```

it looks like Keycloak is expecting a `client secret`, which based on your configuration:

```
let instance = {
    url: "http://localhost:8080",
    realm: "my-realm",
    clientId: "my-client"
};
```

infers that the client `my-client` is a confidential one. However, since you are using the `javascript` adapter, you should actually create a *public* client instead of a *confidential* one.

So change the `access-type` of the client `my-client` from *confidential* to *public*.